# Creating a GUI to interact with Putty

Tags: windows, forms, putty

I have to build one application which on button click starts passing command with putty.exe how can it be done with process.start ?

```
Process.start(@"C:\putty.exe")
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName=@"C:\putty.exe"
startInfo.Arguments = "some load session";
```

this is my current code but i want to push certain script and commands to putty terminal as well

Comment: You may want to look into Plink: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink It supports command-line options of the sort you could pass to it with something like process.start

Comment: please help me with above codes if you can

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PuTTY's command line support is rather minimal, but the `-m` option may work:

From [http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)

> 3.8.3.6 -m: read a remote command or script from a file
>
> The -m option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section 4.18.1). However, the -m option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.
>
> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers. In particular, it is known not to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers.

You'll have to put your command(s) in a file before and pass *that* to PuTTY, but for simple tasks, it could work.

As mentioned in a comment on the question, [Plink](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) sounds much more amenable to what you're trying to do, as  it (appears to) support a fully interactive session via the `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` properties on the object you'll get back from `Process.Start()`.